# Keep Http Connection request header alive in angular with spring security

Tags: angular, typescript

I am trying to convert AngularJS project into Angular 4. For that I am facing one problem with keep Http connection alive after I logged into the app.

My request look like:

`POST /myapp-services/login.html?username=admin&password=admin`

In both the angular versions I am getting 202 as response code after login form submission. I found one major difference about `Connection` header. In AngularJS there is no any `connection: close` but in Angular 4 I found `connection: close`. The problem I am facing is with Angular 4. I am not able to proceed with the subsequent requests in Angular 4 and it is redirecting me the loign.html again and again. Basically I am trying to implement login to the app before making any request to the server. Where is the problem?

I am using proxy.config in Angular 4:

```
{
    "/myapp-services":{
        "target":"https://localhost:8443/",
        "secure":false,
        "loglevel":"debug"
    }
}
```

Below is my response and request headers in both versions.

**AngularJS:**

`General:`

```
Request URL: https://localhost:8443/myapp-services/login.html?username=admin&password=admin
Request Method: POST
Status Code: 200 OK
Remote Address: [::1]:8443
Referrer Policy: no-referrer-when-downgrade
```

`Response Headers:`

```
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: x-requested-with, Content-Type
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST, GET, PUT, OPTIONS, DELETE
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Max-Age: 3600
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
Content-Length: 0
Date: Tue, 10 Jul 2018 08:27:03 GMT
Expires: 0
Pragma: no-cache
Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID=9A05186F8DF53656747EDFA7567E7A4E; Path=/myapp-services; Secure; HttpOnly
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000 ; includeSubDomains
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-Frame-Options: DENY
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
```

`Request Headers:`

```
Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9,hi;q=0.8,es;q=0.7
Cache-Control: no-cache
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 0
Cookie: JSESSIONID=07CB8F42CB8B582768E0813C18AA733F
Host: localhost:8443
Origin: https://localhost:8443
Pragma: no-cache
Referer: https://localhost:8443/myapp-services/login.html
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/67.0.3396.99 Safari/537.36
```

**Angular 4:**

`General:`

```
Request URL: http://localhost:4200/myapp-services/login.html?username=admin&password=admin
Request Method: POST
Status Code: 200 OK
Remote Address: 127.0.0.1:4200
Referrer Policy: no-referrer-when-downgrade
```

`Response Headers:`

```
access-control-allow-headers: x-requested-with, Content-Type
access-control-allow-methods: POST, GET, PUT, OPTIONS, DELETE
access-control-allow-origin: *
access-control-max-age: 3600
cache-control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
connection: close
content-length: 0
date: Tue, 10 Jul 2018 08:30:04 GMT
expires: 0
pragma: no-cache
server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
set-cookie: JSESSIONID=02F1318A13C4A08CA3A0D4E9E1816E5A; Path=/myapp-services; Secure; HttpOnly
strict-transport-security: max-age=31536000 ; includeSubDomains
x-content-type-options: nosniff
x-frame-options: DENY
X-Powered-By: Express
x-xss-protection: 1; mode=block
```

`Request Headers:`

```
Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9,hi;q=0.8,es;q=0.7
Cache-Control: no-cache
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 0
Content-Type: application/json
Host: localhost:4200
Origin: http://localhost:4200
Pragma: no-cache
Referer: http://localhost:4200/login
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/67.0.3396.99 Safari/537.36
X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest
```

Comment: Unrelated to the question, using `username=admin&password=admin` in query string is not recommended as it poses security risk.  web server logs typically logs query strings, and one can easily find out the passwords of users from it.

Comment: Yes! That is not my current problem. That I will fix as part of my security vulnerability fix sprint.

Comment: `Cookie: JSESSIONID=07CB8F42CB8B582768E0813C18AA733F` is not present in your Angular 4 request headers.  Looks like you are using angular dev server localhost:4200 - and not talking to a Tomcat like you are doing in your first example.   You may have to look at that part

Comment: Yes! That is the problem, but not able to find out a solution. Do you mean it will work in production?

Comment: I am not sure whether your design is correct.  You should not be doing `HTTP GET` on `login.html` with user name and password - instead, you should be making a call to Login API using `Http` object from your `LoginComponent`

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was SSL configuration issue. My server was on HTTPS and I was sending data over HTTP. In that case I had to enable SSL in angular. Starting server with ssl true worked for me `ng serve --proxy-config proxy.config.json --ssl true`